# What was British spy Greville Wynne supposed to be selling?

Tags: soviet-union, trade, espionage

I'm researching a history of the British hippy movement. I've interviewed an old hippy who claimed that he traveled to India along the hippy trail in a vehicle that had been converted for British spy [Greville Wynne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greville_Wynne), who used the vehicle in trade shows in the Soviet bloc. Wynne used these occasions to collect information from Oleg Penkovsky, 'the spy who saved the world.'But what I can't seem to find out is what Wynne was actually purporting to sell. I'd be grateful for any information.

Comment: What is insufficient about the information in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greville_Wynne)?  What research have you done?  All questions should document [preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786) What sources have you consulted?  Going to trade shows can also be a buying trip; he might not have claimed to be selling anything, but to have been examining Soviet wares for potential purchase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Greville Wynne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greville_Wynne) was an [electrical engineer](http://spartacus-educational.com/SSwynne.htm). His businesses, which became his cover, sold electrical equipment.

Comment: I wondered what sort; white goods? Or high-tech? For households or industry?

Answer (score 1):

In his book Man from Odessa there is a photo of his sales trailer. One of the companies was Marshall Richards from Crook, County Durham, England.
My father and grandfather worked for this company and mentioned when Wynne visited at the beginning of the 60's when my father was an apprentice.

Comment: Would be useful to include information on what Marshell Richard made since it was presumably what your Father did. Google seems to suggest machine tools, including wire and pipe drawing equipment.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as to *what* was being sold.